# Cardinality of binary sequences with finitely many 1s

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

First of all, sorry if I repost about this issue, couldn't found nothing similar about it.

Let $A$ be the set of all the infinite binary sequences.

How do I find the cardinality of set $B$ - which is the set of all sequences with finite number of $1$s?

I thought about trying to map each subset to the natural number , but it looks I have duplications in my way.

Thanks!

Comment: Um, what is the purpose of defining $A$ here? You never mention it again after defining it.

Comment: I Just mentioned to say that $B$ is a subset of $A$ , which is obvious.

Comment: x @Barak. No, that is not obvious. (-1 for expecting other users to read minds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look like homework, so I'm just giving hints.

First consider separately the cases of one 1, then two 1's, etc.  What cardinality do you get for each specific number of 1's?

Then add up all those cardinalities to get a total for every finite number of 1's (but no strings with infinitely many 1's).  You should get a product of two infinite cardinalities.  What product is that?  What single cardinality is that product equal to?

The same method applies also to roots of different degree polynomial equations with integer coefficients, that is the cardinality of the algebraic numbers.